# RPART - features types

Tags: r, tree, machine-learning, rpart

RPART uses a different splitting procedure for continuous, ordinal and categorical variables. Is there a way to "inform" RPART about the variable type? For illustration, I have an ordinal variable with integer values (1,..,5). Right now, I need to coerce it into characters so RPART will not split it like a continuous variable.

I would like to refrain from changing all my variable types, just for RPART. I would prefer to declare it, somehow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that how is R to know that `foo <- c(1,2,3,2,4,5,1,5)` (for example) is not numeric variable? If you look at the class of `foo` you'll see it is numeric.

```
R> class(foo)
[1] "numeric"
```

The problem you have is that at a very basic level you didn't tell R what the data types were. The simple solution in this case is *not* to convert this to a character vector, but to convert it to an ordered factor. If only for the fact that this is what the data is! **rpart** should pick up the factor aspect and treat it accordingly.

Therefore, the way to inform **rpart** that the variable is ordinal is to tell R that it is ordinal

```
foo <- as.ordered(foo)

R> foo
[1] 1 2 3 2 4 5 1 5
Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5
```

I suspect you are missing out on other features of R because you fail to tell it the nature of the data. R is making an assumption about it which is not correct.